# Perforce client root remapping

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am very new to Perforce so this might be a dumb question.

All the sources I work against are checked out in a Linux server and the location is shared via Samba. I  mount that location on a client Windows machine so I can work but I am finding I cannot use the local Perforce binary on my client machine because of workspace path mismatches.

Can I configure p4 clients so that I can "remap" workspace paths locally?

Comment: I'm not following you.  You are checking out the files on a Linux machine, and then trying to perform Perforce actions upon those shared files via a Windows machine?  That doesn't make sense to me.  Why don't you just point your Windows Perforce client at the Perforce server and check them out on the Windows machine?

Comment: The code is linux specific, wont build on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [AltRoots](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/cmdref/client.html) field in the client spec. It should let you specify that the two directory paths are the same client.

Comment: This should work for the specified situation (workspace hosted on both Linux and Windows) if you don't specify the host, which is optional. I wasn't aware of this because I always specify the host for P4 workspaces.